# Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' when migrating from worklight 6.1 to 7.1

Tags: migration, ibm-mobilefirst, single-sign-on

I am migrating worklight project from WL 6.1 to MobileFirst 7.1. But when deploying the application in MobileFirst Studio 7.1, I got this error

```
    error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /Common_Shell [project Common_Shell]
Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] Common_Shell: worklight///192.168.181.1: 2016-10-15T13:57:56.842Z: Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.Throwable: Error creating bean with name &#39;loginConfigurationServiceBean&#39; defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed&#59; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.verifyServletInitialized(AuthenticationFilter.java:589)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:145)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at [internal classes]
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.Throwable: Error creating bean with name 'loginConfigurationServiceBean' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/C:/workspace/MobileFirstServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-7.1.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    ... 8 more
```

I tried to figure out what might cause that error, and I found that when removing `sso="true"`and `ssoDeviceLoginModule` from `authenticationConfig.xml`, the deployment is done successfully

I know that inconsistent configuration of `sso`and `ssoDeviceLoginModule` may cause some errors. but I am sure it is consistent as it is also works fine on WL6.1.

**Edit:**

- I am using two different versions of worklight studio(6.1 & 7.1) with
  two separate workspaces for both projects.
- I am trying to deploy using worklight studio.*(right-click --> Run AS --> Run On MobileFirst Dev Server)*

Comment: Provide more information... is this a deployment in studio? Can you provide the project for debugging? Is this with a new workspace or the same one as the 6.1? can you import the 6.1 projet into a new workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is lacking numerous details. My suggestion is for you to make sure you're making your project migration in a clean environment.

1. Install Eclipse Mars.
2. Create a new workspace for it.
3. Install MobileFirst Studio 7.1 on it.
4. In your Eclipse with Worklight Studio 6.1, export your project
5. Import the project to the Eclipse with MobileFirst Studio v7.1

The import should pass.
If it doesn't, you need to open a PMR and provide your project to the support team. Stack Overflow is not the medium for this question.

Comment: I followed the steps above & still get the same error. I don't know what is wrong with sso in MobileFirst 7.1 !